# NSDebugDescription=Caught exception during archival: -[TCHMembers encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift

i'm trying to store data from API in my NSObject class and then save it to core data. The response have one variable with data type TCHMembers, which is of twilio class, this TCHMembers is a NSObject class and it has some methods that has to be call in further code. Now when i try to store it in core data entity through NSKeyedArchive the app go to catch bllock and throughs an error, `NSDebugDescription=Caught exception during archival: -[TCHMembers encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` . How i can store it in my core data, i think data type is giving this error, how i can store that?

```
 let createdBy = items.twChannelObj?.createdBy
                let dateCreated = items.twChannelObj?.dateCreated
                let dateCreatedAsDate = items.twChannelObj?.dateCreatedAsDate
                let dateUpdatedAsDate = items.twChannelObj?.dateUpdatedAsDate
                let dateUpdated = items.twChannelObj?.dateUpdated
                let friendlyName = items.twChannelObj?.friendlyName
                let lastMessageDate = items.twChannelObj?.lastMessageDate
                let lastMessageIndex = items.twChannelObj?.lastMessageIndex
                let members = items.twChannelObj?.members
                let messages = items.twChannelObj?.messages
                let sid = items.twChannelObj?.sid
                let status = items.twChannelObj?.status
                let synchronizationStatus = items.twChannelObj?.synchronizationStatus
                let type = items.twChannelObj?.type
                var uniqueName = items.twChannelObj?.uniqueName
                if uniqueName == nil
                {
                    uniqueName = ""
                }

                let channelObject : ChannelObject = ChannelObject.init(createdBy: createdBy!, dateCreated: dateCreated!, dateCreatedAsDate: dateCreatedAsDate!, dateUpdatedAsDate: dateUpdatedAsDate!, dateUpdated: dateUpdated!, friendlyName: friendlyName!, lastMessageDate: lastMessageDate!, lastMessageIndex: lastMessageIndex!, members: members!, messages: messages!, sid: sid!, synchronizationStatus: synchronizationStatus!.rawValue, type: type!.rawValue, uniqueName: uniqueName!,status:status!.rawValue)
                do
                {
                    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                        let dataMember = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: channelObject, requiringSecureCoding: false)
                        user.setValue(dataMember, forKey: "twChannelObj")
                    } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    print("Error \(error)")
                }
```

Comment: As I said in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227003/nskeyedarchiver-issue-in-ios) you have to adopt `NSCoding` in `TCHMembers` and implement `init(coder` and `encode(with`.

Comment: Yeah i have followed your way of NSCoding and its protocols, i have extracted the variables from TCHMembers in my custom NSObject class and then store values in them and then i pass that NSObject value in my array and NSArchieved that and store in my core data as Data type which is working fine now, but this is another class name TCHChannel, i dig in to the class and i got there are some methods only in TCHChannel class no variables are found in class, i want to get these methods how can i get that? @vadian

Comment: this is link for class reference, https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/chat/releases/0.16.0/docs/Classes/TCHMembers.html.  @vadian

Comment: It makes no sense to serialize methods.

Comment: i want this from class /** The members list object for this channel. */
property (nonatomic, strong, readonly, nullable) TCHMembers *members;. @vadian

Comment: You cannot add `NSCoding` conformance to a class because the `init` method must be declared in the class, not in the extension. You need to find another way to map the required information of the class.

Comment: that's what i'm looking for is there any other way or you can guide? @vadian

Comment: I don't know. The question is too broad.